# Display HTML special characters in Angular 2 bindings?

Tags: angular

I have a normal binding like this `{{foo}}` and it displays foo's value as text in the HTML.  The text that comes from the server is `"R&amp;D"`.  I need this to display as "R&D".  Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 html binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`{{}}` is for string binding.

Use attribute binding to `innerHTML` instead to get these characters displayed correctly.

```
<div [innerHTML]="foo">
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/217408 for more details.

Answer (score 29):

For a little more fun and flexibility, you can create a pipe that parses HTML entities:

```ts
@Pipe({name: "decodeHtmlString"})
export class DecodeHtmlString implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {
        const tempElement = document.createElement("div")
        tempElement.innerHTML = value
        return tempElement.innerText
    }
}

{{foo | decodeHtmlString}}
```

Comment: I would suggest that this be a better answer in that I needed to parse some HTML entities on a "title" attribute for which innerHTML was not the answer. Creating a custom pipe and using that solved my issue.

Comment: This works better for me, I needed to decode html to a input placeholder attribute.

Comment: using a hybrid of this, and the accepted answer... makes sense to set the innerHTML directly when possible, and the pipe in other cases.

Comment: after struggling with SafeHtml and bypassSecurityTrustHtml etc. etc. 
This is exaclty what i wanted!

Comment: This also works on input value binding, which is what I needed `<input [value]="fullName | decodeHtmlString">`

Comment: Instead of using `innerText` should use `innerHTML` that way we decode special characters and keep existing html formatting

Comment: @ImantsVolkovs That doesn't decode the special characters though, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. If you set `innerHTML` to `R&amp;D` and return `innerHTML`, you still get `R&amp;D` back instead of `R&D`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It was to resolve special characters from languages instead of amp symbol. Then yeah, it is better to use `innerText`.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to use `[innerHTML]`, you can use unicode string characters (if you're using unicode strings in your project).

For the '&' symbol, that would be U+0026:

`<div>{{"R\u0026D"}}</div>`

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me in some scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the innerHTML like this:

```
 <span [innerHTML]= "foo"></span>
```

It will decode properly

Answer (score 5):

While `innerHTML` will work, it will break the line and `div` will be displayed in the new line (if div is what you prefer to use). Use `outerHTML` instead. It will add the value of `foo` at the same place where you use it.

```
<div [outerHTML]="foo"> </div>
```

With `innerHTML`, span is a better option.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try the binding like this {{"\u0026"}}

Comment: this is much better since it works in {{ }}. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Base on accepted answer, I made an sample used

I shared for whom concern.

```
TS file
    export class AppComponent  {
      cubicSymbol = 'm&sup2;';
    }
HTML file
    <h2>Symbol: <span [innerHTML]="cubicSymbol"></span></h2>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-symbols

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [innerHTML] you can also replace accented characters with HexCode (from: [Accented Characters and Ligatures in HTML and JavaScript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm))

For example "R&D" will be saved as "R\x26D"

This way you can use normal binding.