# Display special characters in angular meta tags?

Tags: angular, meta

I was trying to create angular meta tags. I want to display "&" in the meta tag content

ex:

```
<meta name = "generator" content = "A & B">
```

but it is displaying as

```
<meta name = "generator" content = "A &amp; B">
```

Comment: Solution 1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding
Solution 2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865954/display-html-special-characters-in-angular-2-bindings

Comment: @MileMijatovic do you think these solution works? I dont think so

Comment: Yes, I think . Did you see these solution ?

Comment: @MileMijatovic yes, because I don't think its eaiser to use innerHTML in index.html file , M i right?

Comment: have you used `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` in meta tags of your page?

Comment: Thanks @MileMijatovic but it didn't solved my issue.

Comment: @PardeepJain i tried adding Content-type but it didn't solved my issue.